# Angular4 store NodeJS data

Tags: node.js, angular

I just got started working with the Angular4 and NodeJS.

I have a signin post request that sends data (e.g. user role, first name, last name) to my angular app and stores it in a variable. However, when I reload the page the variables are empty again.

So I was wondering, is there a way of avoiding this (e.g. fetching the necessary data on every page reload?). Or is there a better practice to store the data that you receive from a post request in angular? Localstorage and sessionstorage dont seem really save to me.

I tried to Google this for a couple of hours, but I couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: Take a look at resolve https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are just navigating from one route to other using
`this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);`

then you can save your data in a service variable or pass it between the routes using `this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { firstName: 'First Name', lastName: 'Last Name' }]);`

Instead if you plan to explicitly reload the page then angular has no control over it as http is stateless protocol.You can consider using LocalStorage or Cookies to save your data if required.

Alternatively check [Angular Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to load the data before initing your component, so that you have all the data available beforehand.